# create datatables jquery dynamically with parameter from query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I use "datatables plugin for jquery" to display the results of a query in mysql.

The user can also select from a dropdown list (dateParam) and a multiselect values (conseiller) that will automatically restrict the results of the query and thus modify the table. Instead of having 5 columns, I have only 3 for example.

This is where I get the following error alert: "... requested unknown parameter 'data.1' (for example) for row 0...".

json result without selecting:

```
[{"name":"CONSEILLER","data":["cons1","cons2","cons3","TOTAL UNITES"]},{"name":"TOTAL UNITES","data":[1,9,2,12]}]
```

json result if I select some parameters:

```
[{"name":"CONSEILLER","data":["cons2","TOTAL UNITES"]},{"name":"TOTAL UNITES","data":[9,9]}]
```

Here a part of my query :

```
<?php
    include("../dbconfig.php");

    if (isset($_GET["dateParam"],$_GET["dateParam2"],$_GET["conseiller"])) {
    $SQL = "
        ...the query...
    ";  
    $result = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $result->execute();
    } else {
    $SQL = "
        ...the query....
    ";  
    $result = $dbh->prepare($SQL);
    $result->execute();
    }   

    $rows = array();
    $rows['name'] = 'CONSEILLER';
    $rows1 = array();
    $rows1['name'] = 'TOTAL UNITES';

    while($row = $result->fetch()) {

         $rows['data'][] = $row['CONSEILLER'];
         $rows1['data'][] = ($row['UNITES']);

    }

    $result = array();
    array_push($result,$rows);
    array_push($result,$rows1);

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // VERSION PHP >= 5.3.3

?>
```

Here is a part of my js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#dt_actions_rae_conseiller').DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "scrollX": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "sAjaxSource": "../query/query_actions_rae_conseiller_dt.php",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "data.0" },
            { "data": "data.1" },
            { "data": "data.2" },
            { "data": "data.3" },
            ],
    });

});

/**
    * Datepicker
*/

$(function() {

        var dateParam = "";
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showAnim: 'drop',
            //showOn: "button",
            //buttonImage: "../icones/calendar.gif",
            //buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function(date){
                dateParam = date;
                }
        });

        var dateParam2 = "";
        $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            showAnim: 'drop',
            //showOn: "button",
            //buttonImage: "../icones/calendar.gif",
            //buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function(date){
                dateParam2 = date;
                }
        });

});

/**
* Multiselect
*/

    $(function(){ 
        $("#conseiller").multiselect({
            //header: 'Choisir conseillers',
            minWidth: 160,
            checkAllText: 'all',
            uncheckAllText: 'no',
            noneSelectedText: 'Conseiller',
            selectedList: 7,
            /* selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
                return numChecked + ' of ' + numTotal + ' checked';
            }, */
            show: ["bounce", 200],
            hide: ["explode", 1000]
        });
        //$('#projet').bind('change', function() {alert('Change'); });  
    });

/**
    * Button
*/

$(function(){
    $('button').click(function() {
        var d1 = $("#datepicker").val();
        var d2 = $("#datepicker2").val();
        var d3 = $("#conseiller").val().join(",");
        $.ajax({
                url: "../query/query_actions_rae_conseiller_dt.php",
                //data: {dateParam:d1, dateParam2:d2},
                type: "get",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json){
                            table = $('#dt_actions_rae_conseiller')
                            .on('preXhr.dt', function ( e, settings, data ) {
                            data.dateParam = d1
                            data.dateParam2 = d2
                            data.conseiller = d3
                            })
                            .DataTable({
                                "destroy": true, // TO REINITIALISE DATATABLE
                                "paging": false,
                                "searching": false,
                                "bInfo": false,
                                "scrollX": true,
                                "bProcessing": true,
                                "bServerSide": true,
                                "sAjaxDataProp": "",
                                "sAjaxSource": "../query/query_actions_rae_conseiller_dt.php",
                                "aoColumns": [
                                { "data": "name" },
                                { "data": "data.0" },
                                { "data": "data.1" },
                                { "data": "data.2" },
                                { "data": "data.3" },
                                ],
                            }); 
                        } // end ajax function
        }); // end ajax
    }); // end click function
}); // end function
```

and my php:

```
<table id="dt_actions_rae_conseiller" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead> // not needed ?
                <tr> // not needed ?
                    <th></th> // not needed ?
                    <th></th> // not needed ?
                    <th></th> // not needed ?
                    <th></th> // not needed ?
                    <th></th> // not needed ?
                </tr> // not needed ?
            </thead> // not needed ?
</table>
```

Thnaks for all !

Comment: I just edited my question. Is it really like that?

Answer (score 1):

Ahem, as Php . net says is not sure to test it whit a rowcount -> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Because most databases won't return the number of rows.
Instead you can first run a query A with a count(*) then use a fetchColumn to have in a var the number of rows that will be obtained and then do your loop only if count > 0

Comment: Thanks Marco. mysql_num_rows($result); do a rowcount no ? I thought that datatables could adapt frome the json result... do something easier.

Comment: mmm, if you do a fetchAll on a single var, you can then use count($array) to obtain the number of element and then based on the result work around it

Comment: In fact my query always gives the same number of rows, the number of columns that change.